# How to convert expression "<<=1" in Java to Python

Tags: java, python

In the code below:

```
for (int N = 2; N <= 128; N <<= 1) {print(N)}
```

It will print: 2,4,8,16,32,64,128

How can I create such loop in Python? So how I could express "<<=1" in Python?

Comment: You could just multiply - `N *= 2`? But Python does have a [compound assignment shift operator](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/operators/) so you can just use this code more or less as is...

Comment: `<<= 1` will be `<<= 1` in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for-loop has to be converted into a while-loop:

```
n = 2
while n <= 128:
    print n
    n <<= 1
```